# How can i send Automatic Invoices to my customers every month

Tags: script, automation, accounting

I want to send my customers automatic invoice every month.
Is there any online website which can do that.

OR any plugin or script i can put on my own server to generate it Automatically

Comment: this is very vague, which accounting software are you using.

Comment: I don't have any software , i was thinkingof something online to send invoices every month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher a developer to write a program for you.  It is something that can easily be done with open source software for databases and such.  You will get a custom solution that is exactly what you want (if you find the right developer), and you can feel good about helping someone put food on the table for another week.  :-)

A really nice option would be to have a website with accounts for your customers to log into and do paperless invoices.  It gives you more control over the information they see, how often you can update it, and you know when and if they have seen it (access logs).  That is something that no "sent" invoice can ever provide.  Never have to hear that they "never got the invoice..."  Then you can accept direct online payments and streamline that too.

Comment: I am a developer too , i was also thinking of writing my own site backend

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in [FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/) to send monthly invoices.

Here's a link that explains how the monthly invoice works: http://community.freshbooks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=4338